# Unable to push Swift code to Heroku because of "GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not being set"

Tags: swift, git, heroku

I am trying to push my Swift code to Heroku via Git. This is the error I am getting:

```
remote: fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
remote: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
git init
git remote add heroku [URL]
export GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1
heroku config:set GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1 --remote origin
```

But still when I try to push code to master, it fails. This is the command I am using to push code:

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check, after your [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) (I would prefer `git init .` to be sure), that you have indeed a `.git/` subfolder created in your current folder.

As long as you don't see it, you would get that error message.